# Dynamically passing text box values in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, hana

Is there a way to pass values of a text box dynamically into a drill down report in SSRS?

Details: I have a report which drills down to a level. What I am trying to achieve is, is there a way that the Main report can take the mouse click and pass the same to the next level and only show the relevant values in drilled report. I am using Visual Studio 2017 to develop my reports with Hana as the data source.

**I am trying to achieve a functionality similar to MSTR, where it passes values dynamically.

Comment: Absolutely! https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/drillthrough-drilldown-subreports-and-nested-data-regions?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but the main report passes values to the subreport via the parameters, so you will need a parameter to pass this value into. You can make this parameter hidden in the subreport so the user never sees it.

Let's say you want the data in `Textbox1` in the main report to appear in `Textbox2` in the subreport. Create a hidden parameter in the subreport to pass this data into, let's call it `Passthrough`. In the parameter list mapping when setting up the navigation link in the main report, assign the value to pass into the `Passthrough` parameter to be:

```
=ReportItems!Textbox1.Value
```

In the subreport, set the Value property for `Textbox2` to be:

```
=Parameters!Passthrough.Value
```

Rinse, repeat for any further subreports.

Comment: Hi Chris,
Thanks a lot for the response. I have a small doubt. Below are the details that I have done so far:

In the main report,  I added the passthrough parameter(=ReportItems!Textbox1.Value) to run the report in the action tab from the text box properties window.
Next in the sub report,the textbox 2 (which should have the drilled value) says =Parameters!Passthrough.Value
Now where I am stuck is, in the Passthrough parameter, what should be the available value?

Comment: @Priyanka2304 You don't need to have any available values for the Passthrough parameter. Available values are used to restrict the user's choice to valid options. Since the user will never see this parameter and only you will be populating the value, you don't need to restrict the choice, just leave Available values blank.